# Mostrar Usuario Logado no dashboard do rails_admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gem

Boa tarde a todos, estou desenvolvendo um projeto em rails 5 utilizando devise, cancancan e rails_admin, oque ocorre é o seguinte, criei alguns tipos de usuários, entre eles cito usuários administradores ( tem permissão de manager total no cancancan ), e usuários comuns que tem alguns restrições, a questão é que todo usuário administrador que eu crio, logo apos a autenticação, já na dashboard principal do rails_admin é mostrado corretamente o nome do usuário autenticado, porem usuários comuns que não tem permissão manage no cancancan , não aparece.

[image: Login com usuário comum]

[image: Login com usuário admin]

Agradeço qualquer ajuda.ob

Answer (score 1):

Caso alguém passe por isso, fiz o seguinte ajuste, criei a linha conforme abaixo, para que o usuário possa gerenciar ser login.

PS. o Ajuste foi feito no ability (cancancan )

```
def initialize(user)
  if user
    if user.kind == 'salesman'
      can :manage, User, id: user.id
end
```